Find the missing angle in the triangle below if the sum of two sides is given
I'm having a hard time solving this problem, so if anyone would be kind enough to point me in the right direction, I'd be forever grateful!

Find the value of the the missing angle in the triangle below, if $AD=a+b$.


EDIT: Thanks for the tip! Duly noted! I'll be wary of this the next time, so please forgive me. :D
So, I can easily determine the following:
$$
\angle ABC=40^\circ\wedge\angle DAC=100^\circ
$$
Now, I'm not sure what to do next. I think maybe we'll have to do an auxiliary construction (another triangle with one of it vertices being either on $\overline{AD}$ or $\overline{AB}$ because we have to use the given sum). That's one way to potentially solve it, I think? This is probably not so tough, but I just despise geometry. :sob:

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Use the law of sines to get a relation between $a$ and $b$. The $ABC$ and $CAD$ angles are easily determined. From there and again the law of sines, you can get $\delta$.

Are you able to use trig or you have to solve it without trig? To solve without trig you would have to come up with some additional construction.

@Vasili, trig is allowed, but it'd be nice to see where the given sum comes into play; it has kinda piqued my interest, haha. :p

@PinkBlack: $\frac{DC}{\sin 100^\circ}=\frac{b}{\sin \delta}$. You can express $DC$ in terms of $AD=a+b, b$ using law of cosines, you can express $a$ in terms of $b$ using law of sines applied to $\triangle ABC$

Let $E$ be the point on $AD$ such that $AE = AC$, then $DE = BC$. It's easy to show that $∠CEA = ∠ECA = 40°$ and that $∠ABC = 40°$. This means that $∠CEB = ∠CBE = 40°$, and $\Delta BCE$ is isosceles. $CB = CE = ED$, then $\Delta DEC$ is isosceles, too, and $∠CDE = 20°$.


Thank you so much! I got it now! Keep on rockin'! :D

Hint:

Determine $\angle DAE=\angle DEA$ and find two pairs of congruent triangles
